# Django: Save JSON to database using Fetch/Post

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, fetch

In a Django app, I want to save JSON to the database using the fetch/post API. Two issues: (1) I'm having CSRF verification troubles, and (2) I'm unsure about using POST to modify the DB in general.

I have a model "Job" with a field that should hold JSON.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    job_id = models.IntegerField()
    setup_json = models.CharField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
```

The JSON is generated thru user interactions on a page. When the press a "save" button I want to write the JSON to the `setup_json` field of the proper job.

I don't want to use a form, because the JSON is stored in JavaScript and not written anywhere on the page. So I get the CSRF token [from the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true) to use directly, like this:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  const csrftoken = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;
</script>
```

(Note: in my "settings.py" file I added the line `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` in order to use this technique.)

Then I have my save button call a function like this:

```
function onPressSave() {
  fetch(`webapp/api/save-json/${jobId}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-CSRF-Token": csrftoken,
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify("test json")
  });
}
```

I get a "POST 403 (Forbidden)" error in the console. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

I'm also a little unsure of what exactly the receiving function should look like. Currently it just looks like this:

```
def save_json(request, id):
    j = Job.objects.get(job_id=id)
    j.setup_json = json.dumps(dict(name="testing"))
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

I ultimately want to retrieve the proper JSON from the POST request, but does it look like I'm on the right track with this function?

Answer (score 1):

Django ORM supports JSONFields for a variety of databases, for example if you are using mySQL backend you can:

```py
from django_mysql.models import JSONField
setup_json = JSONField(null=True)
```

or with PostGreSQL:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
setup_json = JSONField(null=True)
```

And then with your save function you could:

```py
def save_json(request, id):
    # The json you want to save, litterally a python dict {}, or list of dicts [{},{},...]
    json_to_be_saved = {}
    j = Job.objects.get(job_id=id)
    j.setup_json = json_to_be_saved
    j.save()
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

About the 403, It could be that in your settings file you don't have:

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # <- Added in manually, must be at the top of this list
```

Which will need you to pip install: `pip3 install django-cors-headers`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do have django-cors-headers installed. With a function like this, is it even necessary to do a POST request? Or does a GET work just as well?

Comment: Well I've never used Django apart from using its rest-framework where It's almost necessary to use POST, as you can grab the dictionary/json directly with ```request.data.get("key", None)```. The only other way would be the set a string in the url and grab it with ```request.query_params.get("key", None)```, which would expose all the data as url's are not safe, while the data is, providing you are using https. Hope that helps. I use react(+axios) and angular for frontend stuff, where making requests to drf seems alot more simpler than your current code, so unable to help on the js part.

Answer (score 1):

this is something I did a long back ago:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   contentType: 'application/json',
   url: "{% url 'login_verification_view' %}",
   headers: {
       'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
   },
   success: function(j) {
       ...
       your code
   }
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. I'd rather use fetch, so I don't have to load JQuery. Any idea how to adapt this technique?

Comment: I haven't used fetch, your code seems to be fine doing the same, check the variable csrftoken - is it empty string?, also print the output of request - print(request) by temporarily setting up csrf_exempt for view and look for the csrftoken

Comment: I found the problem. I was using the header `X-CSRF-Token` instead of `X-CSRFToken`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: aah, I see, happy programming